Spring auto redirect to auth/login but l want redirect to successful.html how l fix it
I have a registration form in register.html that sends a POST request to the /auth/register endpoint. After submitting the form, I want to redirect the user to successful.html instead of /auth/login . However, it is automatically redirecting to /auth/login instead of successful.html.
File SecurityConfig.java
package com.range.someting.Config;

import com.range.someting.Security.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceimpl;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceimpl) {
        this.userDetailsServiceimpl = userDetailsServiceimpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin(login -> login
                        .loginPage("/auth/login").permitAll())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> 
                auth.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/auth/register").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/register").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceimpl);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}

my Authencation redirect controller for html
File AuthenticationRedirectController.java
package com.range.someting.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthenticationRedirectController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register() {
        return "register";
    }
}

there is my user controller, file UserController.java
package com.range.someting.Controller;

import com.range.someting.Model.User;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerdata(@Valid @ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Registration successful, please sign in.");
        return "successful";  // Redirect to the "successful" view
    }
}


Both AuthenticationRedirectController and UserController have a base mapping of "/auth" which is confusing and possibly messing with things especially because both of those controllers have mappings to /auth/register

I write everything in the UserController, but it stays the same.

and why shouldn't it? successful.htm hasn't been whitelisted.

how l whitelist it

The same as your other URLs.

but its not different endpoint

First of all you have two controllers that map to /auth/register that return different things. If you are using spring thymeleaf, your login method in java should return the name of the template you are using for the login page. If I were you, on success of login I would have the button in html reference the success endpoint, which would go to your java endpoint.
<div>
        <a th:href="@{/register/showStudentRegistrationForm}" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Register New Student</a>
</div>

For example something like this. If you have another question feel free to ask.
